# conditional join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to join two tables on a field that depends on a certain condition:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.$variable = table2.id
```

with

```
$variable = table1.id1 is not null ? table1.id1 : table1.id2
```

can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this

```
IF()
IFNULL(),
COALESCE(),
CASE
```

**Using IF**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
IF(table1.id1 IS NOT NULL,table1.id1, table1.id2)=table2.id;
```

**Using IFNULL**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
IFNULL(table1.id1, table1.id2)=table2.id;
```

**Using COALESCE**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
COALESCE(table1.id1, table1.id2)=table2.id;
```

**Using Case**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
(CASE 
WHEN table1.id1 IS NULL THEN table1.id2
ELSE table1.id1 
END) = table2.id;
```

**Refer** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8076eb/4

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditions and OR in the JOIN:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on 
    (table1.id1 IS NOT NULL AND table1.id1 = table2.id) 
     OR 
    (table1.id1 IS NULL AND table1.id2 = table2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table1 join table2 
    on case when table1.id1 is not null then table1.id1 else table1.id2 end = table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`select * from table1,table2 where ifnull(table1.id1,table1.id2)=table2.id`
```

if the first value in ifnull is null then it uses the second one.

Bye

Comment: Would be better when you switch to Standard SQL's `COALESCE(table1.id1,table1.id2)`