# Conditional join in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I need to do conditional join in MarkLogic like in this sql question [conditional join in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764642/conditional-join-in-sql)

I have template with nullable columns and if value of first column is null I want to use second column for join.

I use optic api with `op:from-view()` method.

Comment: Please elaborate and give a bit more to work with...  Are you accessing your TDE template via an SQL statement or the Optic API?  And if the Optic API are you using op:from-sql() or op:from-view().

Comment: Ok I edited post.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few choices.

On the join clause, you could skip the second option(keys) and use a condition my sample is a [join-inner()](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:join-inner) :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"
 at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

let $plan-t1 := op:from-literals((
        map:entry("col1", 1) => map:with("col2", "A"),
        map:entry("col2", "B")
        ), "T1")
            
let $plan-t2 := op:from-literals((
        map:entry("col3", 1) => map:with("col4", "C"),
        map:entry("col3", 2) => map:with("col4", "B")
        ), "T2")
            
let $join := $plan-t2            
        =>op:join-inner(
          $plan-t1,
          (),              
            op:or((
              op:and((
                op:is-defined(op:view-col("T1", "col1")),
                op:eq(op:view-col("T1", "col1"), op:view-col("T2", "col3"))
                )),
              op:and((
                op:not(op:is-defined(op:view-col("T1", "col1"))), 
                op:eq(op:view-col("T1", "col2"), op:view-col("T2", "col4"))
                ))
            ))
          )
                    
return $join=> op:result()
```

[image]

As a second option, one might consider a SQL COALESCE() style approach with op:bind() and op:case() on the first table to resolve the key in advance and then use the join keys. This would be interesting as it may perform quite differently on a database with multiple forests and multiple nodes.

Comment: Thanks for help, I modify your solution with op:case and op:when and It works exactly how I need it.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: This solution is fine when documents count in database are less then 1k because more document creates problems with performance.

Comment: I have used similar to my sample on tens of millions of documents on a 3node cluster and get decent results. How you build an optic plan spring, grouping,  binding columns to make better join keys etc makes a difference just like in SQL (sub query, joins etc).  The layout of your nodes, CPU, memory caches also make a difference.  Also, you state that your solution used op:case and op:when - which would be a different approach from the sample. Perhaps open a new item with your sample query.